# Trying to set up Polyglot notebook to work with Python and R

Tags: python, r, .net, visual-studio-code, polyglot-notebooks

I recently installed the Polyglot notebook extension for VS Code, and I am trying to set it up to work with Python and R. According to [the developer's tutorial](https://github.com/dotnet/interactive/blob/main/docs/jupyter-in-polyglot-notebooks.md), it should be a simple matter of running the following lines in a notebook cell (i am not using Anaconda, and R is already configured for Jupyter notebooks):

```
#!connect jupyter --kernel-name pythonkernel --kernel-spec python3
#!connect jupyter --kernel-name Rkernel --kernel-spec ir
```

Executing a cell run with either of these commands will result in the cell timer running indefinitely without any errors. However, nothing happens.

When posting here, I tried retrieving the version using `#!about` as suggested in the issue template. Like the above commands,  the cell timer runs like the cell is being executed but nothing is happening.

Seemingly, Polyglot notebook is not set up correctly, so I am wondering what I can do to get it to work?

---

##### Edit:

Anyway, I checked the Polyglot notebook: diagnostics console output, and it keeps reiterating the following message indefinitely:

```
Process 'dotnet' with PID 2588758 exited with code 150 and signal null
Started process 2588770: dotnet tool run dotnet-interactive -- notebook-parser
process 2588770 stderr: You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /home/pal_bjartan/.nuget/packages/microsoft.dotnet-interactive/1.0.456201/tools/net7.0/any/Microsoft.DotNet.Interactive.App.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '7.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/

No frameworks were found.

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=7.0.0&arch=x64&rid=arch-x64
```

According to the [linked guide](https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed) above, it seems this error is caused by the required framework either being missing or not installed correctly. However, querying the package manager, the necessary packages seems to be installed:

```
> pacman -Qs dotnet                                                                             1
local/dotnet-host 7.0.13.sdk113-1
    A generic driver for the .NET Core Command Line Interface
local/dotnet-runtime 7.0.13.sdk113-1
    The .NET Core runtime
local/dotnet-sdk 7.0.13.sdk113-1
    The .NET Core SDK
local/dotnet-targeting-pack 7.0.13.sdk113-1
    The .NET Core targeting pack
```

---

.NET:

```
v. 7.0.113
```

VS Code:

```
Version: 1.84.2
Commit: 1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e
Date: 2023-11-09T10:50:47.800Z
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: 24603566
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.6.1-arch1-1
```

Extensions:

```
.NET Install Tool: v2.0.0
Polyglot Notebooks: v1.0.4562011 Pre-Release
```

Comment: When a cell is running indefinitely, it often means that there's an error that's not being displayed in the notebook. You can check the console in VS Code for any error messages. To open the console, go to View -> Output, and then select "Jupyter" from the dropdown menu.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I did check the output of Polyglot diagnostics, which seems to throw the same error repeatedly. I've added the output to my OP.

Comment: Have you added the environment path variable of dotnet in linux? You can use command `dotnet --version` to check it.

Comment: Yes, apparently no issues there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue is with a [missing package](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/.NET#It_was_not_possible_to_find_any_compatible_framework_version) when I installed .NET from the Arch repo.

Turns out  the runtime is shipped as a separate package in Arch. Installing [`aspnet-runtime`](https://archlinux.org/packages/?name=aspnet-runtime) resolved the issue.

Comment: Hi Pål Bjartan glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)